# Is it possible to check what is the current viewport with PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a category template page, and I need to call 2 different loops based on the viewport, first loop for the mobile and second for desktop.

Only solution that I found is relaying on a cookie, left in browser by some plugin, so not really applicable in my case.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://css-tricks.com/make-client-side-data-available-server-side/) describes a few approaches.  The main one relies on a cookie, like your plugin, so will require a reload the first time the page is hit to get the info server-side.

If that approach doesn't work, there are a few other options at the bottom of the article.

No chance you can make your site responsive, and handle the differences in CSS?

Comment: i can't use css here, the difference in loops is that on mobile it should have infinite scroll, and all others default category page. I already made the infinite scroll loop, but it is not loaded because the default loop is already loaded and `wp_reset_postdata()` is not helping